# Enable Java Logging on Mac OS X without Java Preference app

Tags: java, macos

I'm looking for a way to enable java console logging now that Apple has removed the Java Preferences App. Any Ideas?

Comment: If you run your app from Terminal you should see logs

Comment: If it is your own application and you can use Eclipse for it, the console should also show you a log. You can also enable logging for your own application (see Log4J). If it is an external application, terminal seems to be the best bet.

Comment: Be more specific, it's not clear what you are asking based on the responses so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see exceptions and such, just launch your application from the terminal.

Assuming you have a jar, the syntax is

```
java -jar path-to-my-jar.jar
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! The applet I need to collect logs from is a java web app not a local .jar.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a web app:

In ~/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment edit deployment.properties such that

`deployment.console.startup.mode=SHOW`

Answer (score 0):

There is no official documentation on it, but if you (re)install java from java.com website, you'll get Java Control Panel in your System Preferences.